# React Router - как в зависимости от маршрута рендерить внутри родительского различные дочерние компоненты?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Есть сайт, на котором есть основная неизменная часть с фоном, header-ом и footer-ом, на которой в зависимости от выбранного роута рендерятся разные разделы сайта. Есть пример (взят [отсюда](https://getinstance.info/articles/react/learning-react-router/)), как такой роутинг выглядел раньше:

```
ReactDOM.render((
  <Router>
    <Route component={MainLayout}>
      <Route path="/" component={Home} />
      <Route path="/users" component={UserList} />
      <Route path="/widgets" component={WidgetList} />
    </Route>
  </Router>
), document.getElementById('root'));
```

Где `MainLayout` - это и есть эта основная часть.

Но у меня (React Router 5) подобная схема не работает, показывает ворнинг:
`Warning: You should not use <Route component> and <Route children> in the same route; <Route component> will be ignored`.
И вместо `Home` внутри `MainLayout` рендерится только `Home`. Насколько удается понять, это происходит из-за того, что начиная с версии 4-5 React Router были внесены какие-то изменения, не работают роуты с более чем одним уровнем вложенности. И возможность роутить из родительского компонента, видимо, также пропала.

Но должен быть способ это сделать, так как это распространенная задача, кто знает, поделитесь, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не знаю, правильно ли я понял твой вопрос, но вот накидал пример: https://codesandbox.io/s/recursing-waterfall-zzz92

Comment: ну и этот switch вместе со всеми роутами можно положить в родительский компонент, если нужно.

Comment: Спасибо, оно. А то зациклило на этом Layout'е и невозможности что-либо в него положить.)